# Caching considerations for JDBC and Java

Tags: java, database, caching, jdbc

I am having troubles deciding what cache solution should i choose for database objects from a remote db, accesed using JDBC. Since i have limited experience in the field, and a few hours of google search got me into more confusion, i call for your help.

I am interested very much in solutions with : extremely simple implementation and requirements, acceptable documentation and example of how-to-use, fast performer and easy to change the whole solution in the future (if required).

The solution proposed could lack a huge scale applicability (less than 100 users), but should not lack simplicity.

In other words, i am searching for the maximum results with minimal resources/effort.

P.S. I beg your pardon, i could have been a bit unspecific. I need an application/front end cache, and NOT a server/global cache.

Comment: _"The solution proposed could lack a huge scale applicability (less than 100 users), but should not lack simplicity."_ -- Don't use Cache altogether even if you have couple of thousands of users. Can't go simpler.

Comment: Don't forget that database servers have a cache built in. So that could be your caching layer, and you don't actually need to do anything!

Comment: @time4tea can u clarify the comment? Feel free to get into details, for MySQL engine, for instance.

Comment: @Nishant - that's unacceptable.

Comment: Sure - Basically I'm saying that you shouldn't look to cache anything until you have determined that caching that thing will improve your performance. Premature optimization etc etc. Databases cache data themselves, so quite often the data you are selecting is in memory anyway, so why bother caching it again. Besides, sounds like you have a very small app in any case.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-query-cache.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/buffering-caching.html

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to cache the data that you get from your database to reduce the network/database calls. Following URL has the list of open source Java caching solutions. You can pick any one of them and integrate easily into your system.

http://java-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions

Comment: Ok, i've already take a look at the link, before your post, but..there are many solutions there. I was asking for your expertise/practice to suggest 1-2 solutions, as "better" than the others, according to my stated requests (speed and simplicity mostly).

Comment: I used Apache JCS in the past for a very simple application with limited number of users. I had very good success. Here is the link: http://jakarta.apache.org/jcs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

**ORM** framework such as Hibernate contains cache functionality.

Comment: Do you think that's simple enough? Somehow, i doubt it. Please, prove me wrong.

Comment: ORM is not a simple thing, cache neither. If you want to use cache, it's difficult to keep program simplicity. At least ORM provides out-of -box cache function.